# Specific Android View

Tags: android

I am working on implementing a view to show this specific layout.
[image]

So a user may post something (with their profile picture to the left) then people comment/like the post and after a variable length list of comments, there is an edit text box to add one's own comment.

My question here is what is the best way to achieve such a view? Should I use a sectioned adapter with the "5 likes" and "2 comments" pieces as headers? Or are they just all their own views in a list? I'm still fairly new to creating my own variable length views...

Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you want this implemented. If you only want to display 3 likes and a +N that part is easy. If you want to display as many likes as fit with a +N button that's a bit harder. You have to measure your views and add until only one more can fit and then add the +N button.

Comment: Also, if you only want to display a fixed number of comments and add a "View More Comments" link/button this becomes much easier as well.

Also, do you want this whole thing to scroll if necessary, or just the comments section

Answer (score 1):

Make a LinearLayout(Vertical) as the root, and try follow theese guidelines. If any questions comment :)

[image: uhh]

Comment: +1 for the time and answer. Instead of going with `LinearLayout (vertical` for `A comment to a networking site`, it's better to go with a `ListView`. Don't you think so? It will be easy to manage.

Comment: Yes a ListView would do it too (Just remember to set the height as wrap_content) If you are not that confident in making layout in code then go with list view (easier to make the list items).. Just remember to put whole layout in a scrollview.

Comment: I didn't ask this question. Anyway whole layout in ScrollView? Why??Then it's not good to use ListView in it.

Comment: yes but if you make the height wrap_content it will just stretch the list so you won't have a "scroll inside a scroll".. The reason to put the layout in a scrollview is because the comment section can be very big, and in that case it needs to scroll.

Comment: That's why I told to put the comment section in ListView instead of Vertical LinearLayout. You will get scrolling with ListView, even though you set the height to wrap_content.